# Replace ="Text" with =\"Text\" using Preg_Replace

Tags: php, regex

I would like to replace the following:

`="Dark4Red"`

with

`=\"Dark4Red\"`

The = sign and double quotations are fixed ="..."
I just need to add slashes before double quotations.

```
$content = preg_replace('/="[^a-zA-Z#0-9]"/', '=\"[^a-zA-Z#0-9]\"', $line);
```

The above solution didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Do you NEED to use preg_replace?

Comment: Yes...Preg_replace is necessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`addslashes`](http://php.net/addslashes)?

That aside, you appear to have not read any of the examples on `preg_replace`'s [manual page](http://php.net/preg-replace) - if you had, you'd have known that you capture a subpattern (in this case the contents of the quotes) with parentheses and use `$1` to put them in the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$str = '"Text"';
str_replace('"','\"', $str);
```

Comment: The problem i have other bunch of texts that have " ... I just need the backslash on those " which come in this form: ="...."  CHANGE IT TO =\"...\"

Comment: simple wrap whole text(with bunch of double quotes)in single quote and use str_replace as $str = '"Text" wrpping "in" double "codes"';
echo str_replace('"','\"', $str);

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = preg_replace('#="(.*?)"#', '=\"\1\"', $line);
```

Solved.